# Drop-Down Box in a Selection Query - MS ACCESS

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm working on a selection query in my Access database. in one of my columns I wanted to have a drop-down list with selected data. Unfortunately nothing is showing, and I'm thinking about two Problems that can be responsible for this :

1. The selection wont show up until I link my query to a table where I can modify and select from the drop down list.
2. I made a mistake in developing but can't find anything about that mistake

Here is the details of whats going on :

**What I want**

This image is just the result of my query not linked to a table
[image]

**What I have**

Is an actual drop down list without any data in it (still talking about the result of the query not linked to a table in which modification can be made directly)

**Here is What I did**

[image]

Added the queries and tables I'm working on and then =>

[image]

Selected the column I wanted it to be a drop-down list and then added the following query after changing it to a drop down list

```
    SELECT [SALARIE_nom] & " " & [SALARIE_prenom] 
FROM (T_STATUT_EMPLOI INNER JOIN T_SALARIE_EMPLOI ON T_STATUT_EMPLOI.STATUT_EMPLOI_id = T_SALARIE_EMPLOI.SALARIE_EMPLOI_statut_id) LEFT JOIN R_Select_Salarie ON T_SALARIE_EMPLOI.SALARIE_EMPLOI_salarie_nni = R_Select_Salarie.SALARIE_NNI
    WHERE (((T_STATUT_EMPLOI.STATUT_EMPLOI_statut) Like "*validé*") AND ((T_SALARIE_EMPLOI.SALARIE_EMPLOI_Entreprise) Like "*RTE*"));
```

if I run the sql query on it's own, it gives me the results I want but when trying to see this result in the final table (result table of my query) I got the blank drop-down list.
here is the result I get from executing the query alone :

[image]

So I think it's working.

Thank you in advance for reading my explanation and for your comments

Answer (score 0):

I think that everything was fine, and that it was just a bug. After linking my query to a form I started seing the data in the drop-down list in both the form and query.
But I still Have one small issue which is :

- Not being able to modify or choose from my drop-down List.

**What I did**

I created my form using Forms Assistant in access and then I chosed as data source my query. But I can't modify my form or anything could please suggest something to me.

Thank you !